# Javascript Get Facebook Event to display on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

So I am utterly confused when it comes to javascript at times, I'm typically a VB.net/Windows developer. But I'm trying to do a favor for a friend who owns a card shop.

He wants a page to display his events from Facebook on an HTML page. I know I've seen this before or something similar. I have looked into the Javascript API, but nothing from it makes sense to me in how to get the information from the event to display on screen.

All I found was

```
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}/events",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Does anyone know of something to this effect? Or is there a better method in doing this?

Comment: you need to do this server side with an app access token. you do need a token, and tokens are meant to be kept secret, so you can´t use the js sdk.